# Can i change the delegate for an Object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, protocols

i have a class RequestHandler that takes the requests for some ViewController and fetches data on the web asynchronously. In order to notify the ViewController, it implements a protocol and the ViewController is set as its delegate.

Now, this ViewController is a TableViewController, and when a row is selected, it pushes a second ViewController on the NavigationStack. This second (child) ViewController needs to use the RequestHandler too. How can i make it a delegate for the same RequestHandler instance? And how can i make sure it won't mess with the parent TableViewController once i go back to it?

Comment: You mean the child controller uses the request handler a second time? like in: reusing the same request handler? I think that some code would be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that both view controller would want the same request suggests a design error. The view controllers should display the current state of the Model. They should not directly deal with active network requests.

You should have some group of classes that represent your data. These are called the Model. View controllers should only care about the model while the view is onscreen. So a reasonable pattern looks like this:

- ViewController registers for notifications of changes in the Model
- ViewController updates view with current data from Model.
- ViewController requests an update.
- RequestManager (singleton) creates a new RequestHandler to process it.
- When RequestHandler finishes, it tells RequestManager and is released.
- RequestManager updates Model with new data
- Model alerts registered observers that it has changed.
- ViewController updates view with current data from Model.

Now it doesn't matter if the user is on this view, or has moved to another, or moves to another and comes back. In call cases, any time the model changes, the current view is updated.

Comment: I see what you mean, it makes sense, but i do not know how to apply it in my situation. To be more specific, i have an app that remotely controls a bit torrent client through a rpc. The first TableViewController only shows a few infos, while the second ViewController shows much more. Since i do not want to download ALL the information at once (to save kb) i want the second detail view to be able to fetch and refresh its view with information that shouldn't be downloaded before it is opened. How could it fit in your suggested design?

Comment: I would create a Torrent model object and a TorrentManager to hold all of them. I would then have methods `[torrent fetchBasic]` and `[torrent fetchFull]`. You would hand the `torrent` object between view controllers. `[torrent fetchFull]` would have logic to say "have I already fetched everything? No? Then do so now."

Comment: Just Refactored everything as you said, the torrentManager representing the model. Added an observer (cause the model is changing constantly) and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, is the RequestHandler a class written by you, so you could allow it to take more than one delegates for the implemented protocol (just store the delegates in an NSMutableArray, so you can add reps. remove them as you need)

Now when the new view is created, you can just 'register' it to your RequestHandler. The same way if the view is going to be closed, you could/should deregister it from your RequestHandler.

Comment: While this is correct, I discourage him from doing this. He's using delegates, when in fact he wants to use observers. SDK provides plenty of ways to do this (KVO, NSNotificationCenter etc.), (ab)using multiple delegates will likely end him up in a mess.